# Sending packets with UDP protocol

Tags: c++, qt, udp, qtnetwork

I am using Qt to build a network project. My project sends files as packets, every packet is 1K size, I am using `UDP` protocol.

The problem is when I try to send files with big size in Megabytes, the function `writeDatagram()` hanging and the `for loop` stops (as I feel).

How can I solve that? Here goes code I use for sending packets. The packets stored in vector.

```
for(int i=0;i<vector.size();i++)
{
    char *pkt=(char*)&vector.at(i);
    MsgPacket *p=(MsgPacket*)&vector.at(i);
    UDPSocket->writeDatagram(pkt,sizeof(*p),(*addr),(*port));
    UDPSocket->waitForBytesWritten();
    qDebug()<<"packet"<<i<<"sent";
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `vector`? Please tell me it's not a `vector<char>`. Why can't you just say `sizeof(MsgPacket)`, instead of creating an entire variable for the sake of sizing it? Why are you duplicating your >1MB message into a vector of packets and sending those, as opposed to doing this in a zero-copy fashion? Why are you feeding the packets one-by-one and waiting?

Comment: What I did is : I open a file with size 1 MB for example , then I divided it in packets with size 1 KB for each one and stored these packets in a `vector` with type `Msgpacket` (a structure that I defined earlier to represent a packet) .I cast the type of vector entries to `char` to send it by `writeDatagram()` -show the documentation - .

Comment: The problem with that concept is that if we're talking multi-MB files, then you've just made a 2nd multi-MB copy of your original file (and not even efficiently) in an std::vector of _multiple thousands of packets_ (paying the price for their allocations) that you will immediately discard after sending them. Can you not do the send from the same loop that loads up this vector? And your call can be better expressed as `UDPSocket->writeDatagram(pkt, sizeof(MsgPacket), (*addr), (*port));` and by deleting the `MsgPacket *p` line.

Comment: Why don't you put this into a separate thread or what is wrong about blocking in here? Moreover, show us the receiver code, too, please, and by that I mean more than what you showed for the sender. It is insufficient code amount.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `UDPSocket->waitForBytesWritten();` makes your loop wait until the socket is flushed. Either don't call `UDPSocket->waitForBytesWritten();`, or put this routine in a separate Thread, so it wont block.

Quote of the documentation for `waitForBytesWritten()`:

> This function can operate without an event loop. It is useful when writing non-GUI applications and when performing I/O operations in a non-GUI thread.

Comment: I removed it but the problem still ,
and I tried to send file with size 250 k . 
If every thing worked as it should , 250 packet will be received ,but what actually happen is , 67 packet received .